# Coq: controlling `subst` when we have many equalities

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

If one has *many* hypothesis of the form `a = b` (I find that this happens often when we use`inversion`), is there some way to *prevent* a substitution from happening?

I often have Hypothesis that look like

```
H0: rec = someLargeRecord { field := val1; ...; fieldn := valn }
rel1: some_relation rec rec'
rel2: some_relation rec rec''
equal1: a = b
equal2: b = c
...
equal3: y = z
```

On running `subst` at this point, `rel1`, `rel2` and the like blow up, become something of the form

```
rel1: some_relation someLargeRecord { field := val1; ...; fieldn := valn } rel'
rel2: some_relation someLargeRecord { field := val1; ...; fieldn := valn }
 rel''
```

This is horrible to work with.

I wish to somehow control `subst`, preferably to ask it to not consider `H0`. Is this at all possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell `subst` what variables to substitute.  For instance, the call

```
subst a b y.
```

would substitute `a`, `b` and `c`, but not `rec`. This might not be convenient if you are trying to substitute several variables; in this case, you can put the equation that you want to keep back into the goal before calling `subst`. For example, the following snippet would substitute every variable in your context except for `rec`.

```
revert H0.
subst.
intros H0.
```